# Firebase crontab cleanup

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete GeoLocations in my FirebaseDB that were inserted like this:

```
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {

            dbRef.child("hora").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);    //Executes TIMESTAMP function in firebase server and stores that value
            dbRef.child("hora").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    hora = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());    

                    geoFire.setLocation(hora, new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override       //Save geolocation with timestamp in seconds
                        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                Log.v("Informe","There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                            } else {
                                Log.v("Informe","Location saved on server successfully!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In the database, this would look like this:

```
{
  "geofire" : {
    "1515692377982" : {
      ".priority" : "u1dfw2vsqa",
      "g" : "u2xfw2vsqe",
      "l" : [ 48.25681948174579, 22.430931776762012 ]
    },
    "1515692378159" : {
      ".priority" : "u1dfw2vsqa",
      "g" : "u2xfw2vsqe",
      "l" : [ 48.25681948174579, 22.430931776762012 ]
    }
  },
  "hora" : 1515692378159
}
```

(I dont know why it's inserted twice with just one long touch, though)

I've searched about this, and I know I have to use cloud functions, but I have to know JS, and I dont know it very well, so, may someone want to help me in making a function for deleting data that has been in firebase for more than 1 hour for example?

I know this must be triggered by crontab and HTTPS, but I need to first check that the function works.
Some of the links I've found interesting for this:

[Delete items that have been in the DB for 2 hours](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes)

[Delete old users through crontab and HTTPS](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

It should be a mix of these two links, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it working, so here it is if someone needs a Google Cloud Function for deleting firebase data older than an hour ago (this is set by a key with the timestamp, look at my data model) and now you can schedule a crontab to run the HTTPS request every once in a while.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); 
const ref = admin.database().ref().child('geofire'); //Path to the child that contains the items you want to delete
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 3600000;   //1 Hour

exports.cleanOldFiles = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      const now = Date.now();
      const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
      const lastHour = '' + cutoff; //Must be String in order to put it inside .orderByKey().endAt()

      const query = ref.orderByKey().endAt(lastHour);
      return query.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
          updates[child.key] = null;
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
    });

});
```